# How to use IExceptionHandler in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble using IExceptionHandler in my project.

Do I need to install any NuGet packages?

When I try to use, Visual Studio does not find the reference. He asks if I want to create an interface named IExceptionHandler.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace EventMotors.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IExceptionHandler _exceptionHandler;

        public ErrorController(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
        {
            _exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`IExceptionHandler` is not in asp.net core .  In error action , you can use `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature` to access the exception and the original request path in an error handler controller or page:

```
var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
    HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
{
    ExceptionMessage = "File error thrown";
}
if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Path == "/index")
{
    ExceptionMessage += " from home page";
}
```

Please refer to document :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

[`IExceptionHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.iexceptionhandler) interface was added in .NET 8. 
Here is the [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-5/#iexceptionhandler) of anocconcuing it.
And here is [another blog post](https://anthonygiretti.com/2023/06/14/asp-net-core-8-improved-exception-handling-with-iexceptionhandler/) explain it.

Here is a summary of the blog post

> Multiple can be added, and they’ll be called in the order registered.
>  If an exception handler handles a request, it can return true to stop processing.
>  If an exception isn’t handled by any exception handler, then control falls back to the old behavior and options from the middleware.